# How can I update my returned data from UPD ongoing?

Tags: c#, matlab, visual-studio, udp

I have a problem with my UDP connection to MATLAB. I have to press a button at the moment to get the data I have sent, and to update the `returnData`.

Is there a way around this, I have thought of while loops, but have not yet come by a solution so I am hoping someone in here can help.

And for another question, I am having a bit of trouble with UDP connection. I would like if it could receive the data I am sending. Right now, I have to press a button to open and receive data. I have made it like this because I could not update the data otherwise.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //public UdpClient receivingUdpClient = null;
        public string returnData;
        //public byte[] Receive(ref IPEndPoint remoteEP);
        // private Print print = null;
        //while (true)
        //{
        public UdpClient receivingUdpClient = new UdpClient(8051);
        //bool done = false;
        //Creates an IPEndPoint to record the IP Address and port number of the sender.  
        // The IPEndPoint will allow you to read datagrams sent from any source.
        //while (true)
        //{
        public IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8051);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Visible = false;
            label2.Visible = false;
        }

        void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Visible = false;
            try
            {
                //while (true)
                //{
                // Blocks until a message returns on this socket from a remote host.
                Byte[] receiveBytes = receivingUdpClient.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);

                returnData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);

                Console.WriteLine("This is the message you received " +
                                  returnData.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("This message was sent from " +
                                  RemoteIpEndPoint.Address.ToString() +
                                  " on their port number " +
                                  RemoteIpEndPoint.Port.ToString());
                // }      
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(err.ToString());
            }

            if(returnData != String.Empty)
            {
                button2.PerformClick();
            }
        }

        void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (SPELL.Text == String.Empty)
            {
                SPELL.Text = SPELL.Text + returnData;
                label1.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                SPELL.Text = null;
                SPELL.Text = SPELL.Text + returnData;
                label1.Visible = true;
                label2.Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my small test program in Visual Studio so far.

Comment: One question at a time please.

Comment: What do you mean by "Is there a way around this"? What do you want? Is this a business analysis problem or a programming issue? [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It is the problem of updating the returnData every time I sent data to the program. Not updating by clicking a button, but by when new data is sent.